# Why is vector<int * const> illegal/illogical?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, constants, std

I'm new to C++ :)
I just wanted to create a vector of constant pointers to non-const ints. Thus, I thought, I will have a vector of pointers, whose addresses I may not change.

I wrote:

```
std::vector<int * const> pointers;
```

but cannot compile it (using GCC).

I get 5 errors, starting with:
"initializing argument 1 of 'void operator delete(void*)'"
and
"invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*'"

**Why is this illegal (or illogical) and what has it to do with void pointers?**

Comment: Where and how you're using `pointers`?? Note that `std::vector` has some constraints on the elements it can store!!

Comment: It isn't illogical, just unsupported, it wasn't considered important enough for now.

Answer (score 2):

In short, `vector` requires its template parameter to support a few basic operations, and one of those is item assignment.

`vector` has several operations that require assigning to its items. For instance, whenever a `vector` runs out of space and needs to re-size, it allocates a new block of memory and then copies its information over to the new block. If The item type is `const`, it cannot assign to the new block of memory.

There's not really much point to declaring the parameter to be `const` anyway. What behavior were you attempting to get?

Answer (score 1):

I think a succinct justification for the errors is the following: A vector is a mutable data structure, so you can change the contents of the vector (for instance by using `push_back` or `erase`). When you instantiate the vector template you instantiate code that will attempt to overwrite the contents of the vector, which is prohibited by your declaration of a `int *const`.

If you want a vector that cannot be mutated then you can use a constant reference to a vector, or create a const vector and pass it around by value.